# ipmitool command "Get device ID" invalid

Tags: ipmi, openbmc, ipmitool

Im using "ipmitool -b 6 -t 0x2c raw 6 1" this command in host，but it show two errors "unable to send command:invalid argument" and "unable to send raw command" .

However ，this command worked successfully in bmc.

Is there any step i do wrong or any code,recipe i can check?